# Indexing last dimension of 4D tensor using indexes in last dimension of 3D tensor

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, tensorflow

I need to index the last dimension of a 4D tensor using indexes in the last dimension of a 3D tensor. For example, given the following tensor:

```
X = array([[[[ 0.14127222,  0.37404611,  0.09612721,  0.19907043,  0.84104371,
       0.33678107,  0.03965124,  0.16844736,  0.61240914,  0.02107638],
     [ 0.46010377,  0.4302605 ,  0.95917015,  0.05052149,  0.96033522,
       0.6383985 ,  0.24895258,  0.78746404,  0.42848993,  0.16791814]],

    [[ 0.04889435,  0.82308922,  0.96655923,  0.48346   ,  0.95437383,
       0.87187596,  0.68328151,  0.70910435,  0.14809697,  0.73191095],
     [ 0.9863605 ,  0.93424879,  0.8210592 ,  0.60322001,  0.09030777,
       0.43904245,  0.90761251,  0.97734195,  0.83937746,  0.4611313 ]]],


   [[[ 0.63942727,  0.39519546,  0.96378125,  0.67925937,  0.43680618,
       0.51125503,  0.62897664,  0.38485839,  0.62766846,  0.20661218],
     [ 0.34816242,  0.0278764 ,  0.90386847,  0.82995975,  0.37891653,
       0.78402321,  0.15557263,  0.23951166,  0.69553685,  0.65161346]],

    [[ 0.82596645,  0.81959286,  0.39348156,  0.23748691,  0.4410078 ,
       0.99032742,  0.56643199,  0.00693051,  0.96698697,  0.19360464],
     [ 0.06039541,  0.97289256,  0.81413577,  0.15651002,  0.52284394,
       0.76748494,  0.47697888,  0.05827109,  0.54494079,  0.95826538]]]])
```

I want to extract values from it using the following tensor of indexes:

```
Y = array([[[5, 3],
    [9, 0]],

   [[6, 5],
    [5, 7]]])
```

Obtaining the following tensor:

```
R = array([[[ 0.33678107,  0.05052149],
    [ 0.73191095,  0.9863605 ]],

   [[ 0.62897664,  0.78402321],
    [ 0.99032742,  0.05827109]]])
```

How can I do it in TensorFlow? I solved it with a combination of reduce_sum and tf.one_hot, but it's a memory intensive operation which requires to represent a huge tensor of one hot vectors.

Thank you.

Comment: I added a numpy answer, but I only now realized that you seem to be working exclusively with tensorflow, which I'm unfamiliar with. Please let me know if my answer is not applicable to your use case, as I can't test it against tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

You need [fancy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) of your numpy arrays, i.e. indexing into the first dimensions of `X` with lists/arrays rather than slices:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> i,j,k = np.ogrid[:2,:2,:2]
>>> X[i,j,k,Y]
array([[[ 0.33678107,  0.05052149],
        [ 0.73191095,  0.9863605 ]],

       [[ 0.62897664,  0.78402321],
        [ 0.99032742,  0.05827109]]])
```

To make it a bit less prone to magic numbers, and making use of tuple unpacking:

```
>>> ijk = np.ogrid[[slice(None,k) for k in Y.shape]]
>>> X[(*ijk),Y]
array([[[ 0.33678107,  0.05052149],
        [ 0.73191095,  0.9863605 ]],

       [[ 0.62897664,  0.78402321],
        [ 0.99032742,  0.05827109]]])
```

By passing arrays into `X` for indexing, numpy will interpret the four `(2,2,2,2)`-shaped arrays such that the `[n1,n2,n3,n4]` element of each will be used together to obtain the corresponding element from `X`, and the result preserves the shape of these index arrays.

Comment: Well, your answer uses numpy functions, but the OP asked to operate on tensorflow tensors.

Comment: @sygi yeah, thanks, [I realized that after posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227622/indexing-last-dimension-of-4d-tensor-using-indexes-in-last-dimension-of-3d-tenso/41227669#comment69656145_41227622). I was under the impression that tensorflow tensors might *mainly* be numpy arrays under the hood; I left that comment for OP hoping that the answer can still work. If you know that it doesn't, I'll gladly delete the answer (I just didn't want to do that before some feedback, in case it *does* help)

Comment: @sygi actually, I realized that I installed tensorflow last week, and it seems to me that actual tensorflow tensors are *not* printed as the objects in OP's question. These quantities do seem like numpy arrays, which probably came from `tf.Session().run`. If this is the case, the above solution works perfectly.

Comment: Well, to me it was clear that OP wanted a TF and not numpy solutions (and in that case the solution won't work), but maybe let us leave that to the OP.

Comment: @sygi ah, I see what you mean, I didn't consider that possibility. We'll see when OP responds, thanks for the feedback:)